# Regulating Temperature of Cider Fermentation

Tags: cider, fermentation-temperature, temperature-control

I started a batch of Vimto turbo cider yesterday (22/01/23). It's currently very cold in the UK and I'm concerned the low temperature will negatively impact the brew. I've got the fermentation bin on two towels to keep it off the cold kitchen tile floor. The thermometer strip on the bin is showing 14°C at 1PM but this will drop overnight.

How would I keep it above 10°C overnight without an electric blanket? I've thought about hot water bottles but have read that spikes in the temperature during the fermentation will cause problems with the yeast.

Comment: Are you looking for answers that don't involve some form of electric heating?

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm looking for answers that don't involve any equipment I don't have. So ideally something I can fashion together myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution so bit the bullet the purchased a heat pad. Was about £20 on Amazon.

Comment: If you're using a heat pad with a built-in thermostat, you may find a temp controller like an Inkbird (https://amazon.com/gp/product/B01HXM5UAC/) or Anvil (https://amazon.com/Anvil-Brewing-Equipment-Temperature-Controller/dp/B07V3NNXG9) a nice addition to maintain stable temps within a few degrees of range.

Comment: to be honest, unless it gets below 3 degrees, and you are making some 12% abv or higher, dont worry. use a good active starter with a warm batch of wort and it will kick off fine. then if its cold it will just take longer, but also taste cleaner in the end.